# Netbeans: how to copy files on build?

Tags: c++, netbeans

I`m implementing simple c++ library in Netbeans using make build tool.
I want to copy some header files to folder include/{lib_name} on each build.
How to do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Edit the .build-post target of your project's Makefile. Here is an example:

```
.build-post: .build-impl
# Add your post 'build' code here...
    [ -d include/${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}} ] || mkdir include/${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}
    cp *.h include/${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}}
```

**Lines must be indented with tab characters.** If you copy paste this snippet, it will probably have spaces and you should replace them with a tab character.

The ${CND_ARTIFACT_NAME_${CONF}} is a Makefile variable representing the name and configuration of your library artifact. If that isn't exactly what you want, you could replace the variable with your library name.

Comment: If I`m right make files are generated by Netbeans. Should I configure instead some Netbeans config files?

Comment: The main Makefile has extension points like the .build-post target that you are free to modify. NetBeans does generate sub makefiles in the nbproject folder that you should not edit directly.